# WinError 6 - The handle is invalid with executable but code works on debug mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, inno-setup, pyinstaller

I'm using a software that handle video processing in a powershell subprocess.

With PyCharm, when I run my software (in debug mode) everything works as expected.

When I use pyinstaller and inno setup to make an executable and install it on windows I got this error when Sub process start :

```
  [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

I suppose it’s due to an error in a subprocess like this piece of code :

```
try:
    psa1_path = EnvValues.powershell_path().format(project=project)
    #   using this powershell : C:/Users/${USERNAME}\projects\demo\cmd\powershell.ps1 -m -v 'CC 2018' -wait windowstyle hidden
    dc_logger.info(f'using this powershell : {psa1_path}')
    if project:
        dc_logger.info("PowerShell Rendering Started")
        with open(EnvValues.frame_path(), 'a') as f:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
                                  '-ExecutionPolicy',
                                  'Unrestricted',
                                  psa1_path],
                                 stdout=f)
            p.communicate()
        dc_logger.info("PowerShell Done Rendering")
        return True
    else:
        dc_logger.info("no project to render")
        return False
```

Is the bug related to arguments passed to the subprocess ? Why executable version of the code is the only one not working ? Why I don't have the bug in the development version ?

Here's my pyinstaller cmds :

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w -F -i "C:\Users\my_project\icon.ico" Project.py

pyinstaller --onefile -w -F -i "C:\Users\my_project\icon.ico" Project.spec
```

Then I put this in InnoSetup and I install the output to my windows machine.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? Show us an exception callstack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found my error and post a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `psa1_path` variable

```
C:/Users/${USERNAME}\projects\demo\cmd\powershell.ps1 -m -v 'CC 2018' -wait windowstyle hidden
```

This variable has parameters. And the `subprocess.Popen` use it as a string, then you have to set `shell=True` so Popen will use this string as a complete shell cmd.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
                              '-ExecutionPolicy',
                              'Unrestricted',
                              psa1_path],
                             stdout=f, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Don't forget to add stdin arg because it's also throw the `[WinError 6] The handle is invalid`

So why the code works with debug code and not with executable :

It's mainly because PyCharm does additionnal configuration and setup behind the scenes when it comes to running a program.

Because when you’re going from IDE to runtime, you need additional hooks to get things going. pyinstaller doesn’t do the subprocess the same way as pyCharm for the shell part